# Loading a class from a specific jar on Weblogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, classloader

I have an application deployed on Weblogic and because of a lock contention generated by a Xerces bug i would like to 'force' Weblogic to use the correct jar where the bug is already fixed.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=558581 (xerces bug fixed)

Is there a way to be sure that the class from a specific jar is loaded and used by my application.

By default weblogic is using the old buggy Xerves in multiple internal librares:

```
com.bea.core.apache_1.2.0.0.jar
com.bea.core.apache.xercesImpl_2.8.1.jar
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to set the new JAR in startWeblogic script before other jars. see this link for more options http://stackoverflow.com/q/7187581/289396 you can also try the `prefer-webinf-classes` with the new JAR instead of native Weblogic jar

Comment: I can't use...prefer-webinf-classes.It is an application that I do not package ...

Answer (score 1):

One way is to modify the `CLASSPATH` of Weblogic startup scripts so that it contains the desired jar before the jar containing the buggy version of the library.

You can modify e.g. `domain/bin/setEnv.sh`.

Use `-verbose:class` to verify that the correct version of the Class is loaded.

Comment: What I will try first is similar...using endoresed dir property

Comment: Btw. feel free to post your solution as alternative answer.