# org.apache.axis.message.SOAPBodyElement cannot be cast to weblogic.xml.xmlnode.XMLNode

Tags: java, xml, soap, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have all jars everything in place, when i deploy my application.war file on weblogic server, it always tries to use its own jars for SOAPBodyElement and hence I am getting the exception like -

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.message.SOAPBodyElement cannot be cast to weblogic.xml.xmlnode.XMLNode ..

My code looks like

```
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance(); 
SOAPMessage request = mf.createMessage();
SOAPPart part = request.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope env = part.getEnvelope();
SOAPBody body = env.getBody();
SOAPBodyElement soapBodyElement = new SOAPBodyElement(document);
body.addChildElement(soapBodyElement); // throws exception @ this line
```

Only SOAPBodyElement is from org.apache.axis.message package rest all are from javax.xml.soap package. Is there any way i can override the weblogic preference in my code without altering startup script. Or any other workaround to add the childElement?

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention your preferred libraries by changing the weblogic.xml(in your case of war) or weblogic-application.xml(in case of ear).

For weblogic.xml you got to set prefer-web-inf-classes tag to true so that it will load classes from your web-inf folder

For weblogic-application.xml you can define prefer-application-packages tag

You can refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187581/how-to-set-order-of-jars-in-weblogic)