# How do I change the hour and minute on a joda time DateTime object?

Tags: java, weblogic, jodatime

I've tried the following two options:

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = dt.plusDays(1).withMinuteOfHour(0);
```

and

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = dt.withMinuteOfHour(0);
```

they both report the following error message:

```
Method "withMinuteOfHour" with signature "(I)Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;" is not applicable on this object
```

I'm using joda time 2.3:

```
joda-time:joda-time:2.3
```

Comment: What do you want to change it to ? if the time is say 09:56:35 seconds you want to make it to 09:00:00 ?

Comment: see the examples in the question (yes)

Comment: line 2,3 and line 4,5

Comment: It works fine for me... what's your environment? When are you seeing the error?

Comment: i'm running in weblogic. right. weblogic uses jodatime 1.2, which doesn't have these methods yet - must be some sort of conflict

Comment: @blueberryfields: Right, that would make perfect sense. It would have been nice to have that information from the start :) I suggest you either edit this question significantly and use 1.2 everywhere, or delete the question while you search for a way of making WebLogic use 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracked this to a version conflict between the joda time version included with weblogic, and the one that my application wants to use.

See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187581/how-to-set-order-of-jars-in-weblogic) question for ideas for a workaround - solutions #2/#3 in the accepted answer are probably the correct ones to use (and worked for me in this situation).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = dt.minusMinutes(dt.minuteOfHour()).minusSecond(dt.secondOfMinute());
```