# WebLogic - Jar is there but NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils

Tags: java, maven, jar, weblogic

Getting a deployment error when deploying an ear (myapp.ear)  to weblogic 12.1.3.  Error:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils

Notes:

1. Compiles fine: mvn clean; mvn install
2. The EAR has **APP-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar** which has that class
3. Thought maybe a jar conflict.  weblogic has 2 jars w/ same package.class (wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.apache.commons.io_1.2.0.0_1-4.jar &  wlserver/modules/features/weblogic.server.merged.jar)   but ... those aren't in classpath
4. Tried again w/o adding jar to app (scope=provided - pom.xml) but same error

Actual Error:

```
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:01 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451921167> <BEA-423147> <Exception [com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ActionLookupFailedException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] thrown while trying to do task [handlePostbackData] in class [com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.PageFlowContent].> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922415> <BEA-423405> <An exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] was thrown while rendering the content at [null].> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922415> <BEA-423137> <There was an error loading the requested URI null.> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922431> <BEA-423223> <There was an error while running a lifecycle stage :: Lifecycle: UIControl.render :: for the control :: null ::.> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922446> <BEA-423405> <An exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] was thrown while rendering the content at [/com/bea/console/actions/app/install/Flow.jpf].> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922446> <BEA-423137> <There was an error loading the requested URI /com/bea/console/actions/app/install/Flow.jpf.> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922446> <BEA-423223> <There was an error while running a lifecycle stage :: Lifecycle: UIControl.render :: for the control :: null ::.> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922446> <BEA-423405> <An exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] was thrown while rendering the content at [null].> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922446> <BEA-423137> <There was an error loading the requested URI null.> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922446> <BEA-423223> <There was an error while running a lifecycle stage :: Lifecycle: UIControl.render :: for the control :: null ::.> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922477> <BEA-423405> <An exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] was thrown while rendering the content at [null].> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922477> <BEA-423137> <There was an error loading the requested URI null.> 
####<Apr 7, 2015 8:12:02 PM EDT> <Error> <netuix> <IBMADM-BL787D> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1428451922477> <BEA-423223> <There was an error while running a lifecycle stage :: Lifecycle: UIControl.render :: for the control :: null ::.>
```

Answer (score 0):

See `<prefer-web-inf-classes>` and `<prefer-application-packages>`.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP602

And similar questions like:

[How to set order of jars in WebLogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187581/how-to-set-order-of-jars-in-weblogic)

I would try a `<prefer-application-packages>` solution first.

However, NoClassDef means the class was literally not found. You compiled it but it's no longer on the classpath (so also check the structure of your ear). See: [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception)