# weblogic classloader vs maven dependencies

Tags: maven, weblogic

I have working spring boot app, running in standalone mode. I changed it, so that it build war and can be deployed to application server, and it can, to wildfly, and it works. Now to weblogic. I never used it before, so I'm confused and have to do something wrong.

Basicly upon deploy it complains about missing dependencies, but they are present in war. It seems, that it's because of weblogic classloader, which prefers it's own classes over the ones in war. So I created weblogic.xml file and tried:

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

That's ignored. Ok, then we can do:

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

and that way errors starts to disappear. Great.

But ... this mean, that I'm writing second pom.xml without transitive dependencies! This isn't normal, right? What is the sane way how to deploy on weblogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, customizing the `prefer-application-packages` element as you've started is the right way to do it. The application must explicitly tell WebLogic which packages from the app override packages provided in WebLogic.

WebLogic provides a Classloader Analysis Tool (CAT) that you may use to help find the conflicts. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35895292/944849) for more information.