# Weblogic - Why does deploying a new version of Joda-Time affect SAX parsing?

Tags: java, weblogic, libraries

Environment: Weblogic11g

In my Java program, I'm using a method in **joda-time-1.6.2**. By default, WebLogic comes with **joda.time_1.2.1.0.jar**, which doesn't have the method I need.

So, I put the **joda-time-1.6.2** jar file in WEB-INF/lib and modified the **weblogic.xml** file in my WEB-INF/ folder as follows:

```
<container-descriptor>     
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>   
</container-descriptor>
```

It works, but there is a side effect: I have another program that uses **org.xml.sax** for XML parsing and after the change shown above, the program that uses **org.xml.sax** generates the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type 'tag1' was not declared
```

`tag1` is one of the tags in my XML file.

I can conclude that this happens because of the Joda-Time change shown above, because when I remove that change, XML processing works fine.

Why is that? How can I make sure both Joda-Time and SAX parsing work?

Comment: Could you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187581/how-to-set-order-of-jars-in-weblogic

Comment: @Unknown i tried that before (using weblogic-application.xml), it don't work.